# fql query character encoding

Tags: php, facebook, character-encoding, facebook-fql

I am executing a FQL query, and if I print the array with the results I get wrong characters.

For example instead of `ò` I get `Ã².`

my webpage is set to: `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`

I think it's an issue with facebook and not with me.. Have you experienced something similar and did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Facebook API return results in UTF-8 encoding, you should properly transcode the result to proper encoding before displaying 'em.

Comment: how, is there a way to do this in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results from Facebook are in `UTF-8` encoding.

[`ò` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f2/index.htm) is `c3b2` in UTF-8 (hex) `0xC3 - Ã` `0xB2 - ²`

To convert the results to `ISO-8859-1` from `UTF-8` in PHP you may use [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/utf8_decode) function:

```
$source = chr(0xc3).chr(0xb2);
$result = utf8_decode($source); // -> 0xF2 (ò in ISO-8859-1)
```

Comment: I am executing a fql query to retrieve friends names. This is not the only special character unfortunately! Is there a way to decode and display everything from utf to iso 8859-1?

Comment: @MarkBelli, this is actually the way to decode any string from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1`, code is just a sample to show how to do that and that it's working on the case you provided... just use `$friend_name = utf8_decode($friend_name)` or something like this, beware that some users will have friends with names that cannot be represent in `ISO-8859-1` encoding...

Comment: ok.. I will try that and I will let you know how it goes tomorrow, thanks in the meanwhile!