# Encoding in result of Fql query

Tags: php, facebook, encoding, facebook-fql

```
 $fql = 'SELECT name from user where uid = ' . $user;
            $result = $this->facebook->api(array(
                                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                                       'query' => $fql,
                                     ));
var_dump($result);
```

I select my name from facebook the result is not encoded right `Škofja Loka` is `Å kofja Loka` . I have tried to change this `utf_encode` and `utf_decode`, but it does not work.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656029/fql-query-character-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Š"` is not in ISO-8859-1 so `utf8_decode/utf8_encode`, which convert from and to ISO-8859-1, cannot deal with it. You should never use those functions anyway, PHP is perfectly fine with UTF-8 without any decoding or encoding.

It looks like all you need is the http header for UTF-8 charset though:

```
<?php
//Before any output
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

...


 $fql = 'SELECT name from user where uid = ' . $user;
            $result = $this->facebook->api(array(
                                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                                       'query' => $fql,
                                     ));
var_dump($result);
```